# Voting - Stored procedures

Tags: mysql, stored-procedures, triggers

I'm trying to come up with a nice elegant solution for a voting system like SO's. If there's a way to do it with elegance using triggers I couldn't figure it out so I'm trying with stored procedures. This is what I've come up with, It's not pretty so I'm asking for ideas. I'll probably even have one query rather than the query+stored procedure. But I'd really like to know a clean way to update a user's points and insert/update votes. Points are in a separate table to be updated by procedure.

**Upvote**

```
INSERT INTO votes
ON DUPLICATE KEY
UPDATE votes
SET v.weight = v.weight + 1
WHERE v.weight = 0 OR v.weight = -1
AND v.userid = {$uid}
AND v.itemid = {$itemid}
//call procedure to +1 user points
```

**Downvote**

```
INSERT INTO votes
ON DUPLICATE KEY
UPDATE votes
SET v.weight = v.weight - 1
WHERE v.weight = 1 OR v.weight = 0
AND v.userid = {$uid}
AND v.itemid = {$itemid}
//call procedure to -1
```

**Flipdown (when user changes vote from up to down)**

```
INSERT INTO votes
ON DUPLICATE KEY
UPDATE votes
SET v.weight = -1
WHERE v.weight = 1
AND v.userid = {$uid}
AND v.itemid = {$itemid}
//call procedure to -2
```

**Flipup**

```
INSERT INTO votes
ON DUPLICATE KEY
UPDATE votes
SET v.weight = 0
WHERE v.weight = -1
AND v.userid = {$uid}
AND v.itemid = {$itemid}
//call procedure to +2
```

Comment: I just answered a question similar to the above (though it has nothing to do with stored procedures), read my answer [here](http://stackoverflow.com/a/8617640/1090079) to simplify your current queries.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I assume that `votes` table has 3 columns (post_id, user_id, weight). You can use the following query:

```
insert into votes(post_id, user_id, weight) 
values(post_id_in, user_id_in, weight_in)
on duplicate key update
set
  weight = weight_in;
```

Use should have unique index on(post_id, user_id).

If you denormalize data and table `posts` has column for total votes that you need to recalculate it.

Comment: I'm not really concerned about the insert part.

Comment: Ok. But it does update too. If user already vote in this post it does update with new weight

Comment: I mean I'm concerned with the updating of user points in the separate table.

Comment: If we are talking about sum (total value) of user points. It is better to do the following: 1) before doing update/insert you should get previous vote value; 2) apply to your separate table `total = total - previous_vote_value + current_vote_value`

Comment: I've discovered the NEW and OLD keywords this should be easy enough to do with a trigger.

Answer (score 0):

I personally do not see a need for stored procedure in your case. If you are tracking user votes this means that the user id is available to you. I would suggest opening a mysql transaction perform your insert in the votes table and then perform an update to keep track of the user's score. Then if both calls are successful commit the transaction this will ensure data integrity.

Maybe you could share the specific reasoning why you want to use procedures?